# ¿Por que se guarda formato con corchetes en mi bd al consultar texto de un combobox en laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Intento obtener el texto de un combobox desde el controlador por lo cual hago una consulta a la b.d con el valor del combobox obtenido pero al guardar lo hace con el siguiente formato ["Planta I"](no se por que me guarda con corchete y comillas solo quiero el texto). El codigo del controlador es el siguiente

```
$idpiso=$request->get('pisoroom');
      $nombrepiso=DB::table('levels')->where('id',$idpiso)
      ->pluck('nombre');
$rooms=Room::create([
         'ubicacion'=>$nombrepiso
        ]);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema está dado porque la función **where** devuelve un arreglo por eso lo guarda con el formato [valor] ya que le indicas que vas a dejar de todos los campos solamente el nombre, cuando llamas a **pluck**('nombre')

Si haces lo siguiente te podras dar cuenta de lo que digo:

```
$nombrepiso = (string)DB::table('levels')->where('id',$piso)->pluck('nombre');
dd($nombrepiso);
```

Entonces para que puedas obtener lo que quieres solamente debes llamar a la función first ya que se sobreentiende que solamente quieres 1 y si buscas por el id, siendo este casi siempre llave primaria solo encontrarás 1. Por tanto al hacer esto:

```
$idpiso=$request->get('pisoroom');
$nombrepiso = (string)DB::table('levels')->where('id',$piso)->pluck('name')->first();
$rooms=Room::create([ 'ubicacion'=>$nombrepiso ]);
```

Ya podrás guardar el nombre como esperabas. Espero que te resuelvas con esto.

Comment: Buena! Dariel Ramos Diaz, esto ha solucionado mi problema, gracias.